# Formato de imágenes SVG o PNG en un sitio web con php

Tags: php, svg

actualmente me encuentro realizando un sitio web responsivo en php que requiere de manejo de imágenes, encontré que el formato svg ayuda para que las imágenes no pierdan calidad al cambiar entre dispositivos, por lo que intente cambiar el formato de varias imágenes a este formato, sin embargo refrescar la página tarda mucho tiempo en cargar las imágenes.

Mi duda es si es valido utilizar el formato para imágenes como fotografías o solo es apto para el manejo de iconos, logos o dibujos animados, ya que he visto en otras paginas que se utilizan más para este fin. Ya que no logro comprender el porque demora mucho tiempo si se supone que el archivo en teoría pesa menos.

Espero puedan explicarme ya que apenas soy nueva en el manejo de este tipo de archivos.

Comment: Las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas, por favor lee [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al contrario! Yo solo usaría SVG en casos extremos, pero para tu caso particular (un site *responsive*) utilizaría imágenes en formato PNG.

Como todo, te encontrarás con usuarios que te dirán justo lo contrario, pero la amplia mayoría usa más PNG que no SVG. Además, es lógico, SVG son imágenes vectoriales calculadas al momento (no son pixeles), con lo que quizá es por ese motivo que te tarde en cargar...

Si quieres más info: [aquí](https://www.pagecloud.com/blog/web-images-png-vs-jpg-vs-gif-vs-svg) y [aquí](https://blog.mrdaniels.ch/warz/png-vs-svg-2017/)

Extraigo un texto del 2º enlace que es bastante interesante:

“*What happens when SVG doesn’t really make sense for me, but I need to cater for high-resolution screens and/or mobile devices?*”.

Great question. Simple answer: **you use PNG**.

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo pero en el sitio evitamos responder a preguntas basadas en opiniones

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, me ayudas en orientarme mejor en este tema :).